# Rails 4 and PG:UnableToSend error (connection pool? Timeout?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-postgresql

I'm new to rails and its' ecosystem, and I'm deploying a rails 4 app on nginx/passenger, configured to access a remote postgres db. When a user first accesses the app, it encounters an error, but subsequent accesses succeed, at least for a given session. Here's the error:

```
I, [2013-10-03T16:51:31.826577 #6972]  INFO -- : Processing by ProvisionedInstancesController#index as HTML
E, [2013-10-03T16:51:31.831507 #6972] ERROR -- : PG::UnableToSend: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected
:               SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM pg_class c
          LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
          WHERE c.relkind in ('v','r')
          AND c.relname = 'provisioned_instances'
          AND n.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))

I, [2013-10-03T16:51:31.831832 #6972]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms
```

I haven't come across anything that's really given me a very good understanding of what might be the problem. According to the log, only about 5 ms elapses between entering the controller and the postgres error, so I'm not sure it's actually a timeout issue. Some other search results indicate it might be a connection pool issue, but I'm seeing this error on my very first access of the app, so I presume there isn't a chance for multiple connections to even have been made at this point? (My database.yml uses the default size of 5 for the connection pool).

I've been googling and experimenting for the past day, and I'm pretty stumped at this point.

Comment: I should add that I *believe* that this issue has something to do with also running Sidekiq to process background jobs. I've added a sidekiq initializer that does ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection inside its' configure_server block, but that doesn't seem to have corrected the issue.

Comment: What version of `pg` gem?